# Resize individual dynamically created text input on keyup which has several siblings with same class

Tags: jquery, keyup

Any help would be appreciated on this please. I'm trying to resize a dynamically created text input on keyup. I can get this to work on a basic level but I'm having trouble resizing individual inputs which have the same class — i.e Instead of just one individual input field resizing, all text inputs with class ".question" are resizing.

Here is my code:

```
function resizeInput(theInputField) {
  var getInputWidth = $(theInputField).width();
  if(getInputWidth < 400){
    $(theInputField).attr('size', $(theInputField).val().length);
  }
}

$('#question-list').on('keyup', '.question', function(){
  resizeInput('.question');
});
```

$('#question-list') --> This is a ul element.

$('.question') --> This is a dynamically created input[type="text"] in the above ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler, `this` is the element which triggered the event. You could do something like this:

```
function resizeInput($theInputField) {      
  var inputWidth = $theInputField.width();
  if(inputWidth < 400){
    $theInputField.attr('size', $theInputField.val().length);
  }
}

$('#question-list').on('keyup', '.question', function(){
  resizeInput($(this));
});
```

Comment: I know this was asked a while ago now but thanks! You was indeed spot on with your use of `$(this)`. I could kick myself for not figuring that out! :)